# how to run deepfacelive on my python using windows

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, deepface

Below is what I get after trying to run deepfacelive on my Anaconda. I am using a windows computer.

```
(tudazdeep) C:\Users\owner\Desktop\DeepFaceLive-master>python main.py run DeepFaceLive--userdata-dirC:\Users\owner\Desktop\DeepFaceLive-master
usage: main.py run [-h] {DeepFaceLive} ...
main.py run: error: argument {DeepFaceLive}: invalid choice: 'DeepFaceLive--userdata-dirC:\\Users\\owner\\Desktop\\DeepFaceLive-master' (choose from 'DeepFaceLive')
```

Trying to run deepfacelive on my python